# Pass NSDate in NSDictionary and convert into NSData for jsondata fix

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdate, nsdictionary

I have a json having `NSString` and `NSDate` data (dob)
I create an `NSDictionary` of it, but when I am converting it into data using code

```
 NSData *requestData1 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:json_inputDic options:0 error:&error];
```

It kills by giving error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__NSDate)'
```

My problem is that i need to pass dob as NSDate is mandatory. How do I fix it?

For example

```
   NSDate *newDate = [NSDate date];
    [dic setValue:newDate forKey:@"dob"];


    NSString *good = @"good";

    [dic setValue:good forKey:@"good"];

    NSLog(@"dic=%@",dic);
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error]; //it gives error

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonString);
```

Comment: Why not convert NSDate to NSString of the desired format and create JSON data from it.

Comment: it need to be pass in API , as it manadory as NSDate

Comment: Sure, the dob might be a `NSDate`, but presuming you're sending this to some web service, that web server probably doesn't even know what a `NSDate` is. It has its own data type for dates. The question is in what format does this web service expect the birthday to be represented. Is it `yyyy-MM-dd`? `dd/MM/yyyy`? Possibly even just `dd/MM`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSDate` cannot be represented in JSON natively. As `NSJSONSerialization` documentation says:

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following properties:
>
> - The top level object is an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.
> - All objects are instances of `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, or `NSNull`.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of `NSString`.
> - Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

It's unclear from your question in what format the date should be represented in your JSON. Often, you format dates in some standard date string format (e.g. ISO 8601/RFC 3339 format like `2016-01-25T06:54:00Z`).

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ";
```

Or, for macOS 10.12 and iOS 10, you can do:

```
NSISO8601DateFormatter *formatter = [[NSISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
```

Then:

```
NSString *birthDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:birthDate];
```

See [Apple Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) for more information.

Or perhaps, because it's a birthday, you only need `yyyy-MM-dd`.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSString *birthDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:birthDate];
```

Bottom line, you have to tell us what format your web service is expecting the dates to be formatted, and then we can help you format it accordingly.

Comment: `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` and `init(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:)` of `NSDate` do good job as well.